# bash function syntax error in cygwin

Tags: bash, function, syntax, cygwin

I'm using cygwin. I made a sh file like the following

```
#!/bin/sh
function bash {
local var="local variable"
echo $var
}

then I execute this file 
./test.sh
```

The result returned is

```
./test.sh
./test.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'/test.sh: line 2: `function bash {
```

I have no clue how to fix it and use the capability of writing function in bash scripts. Thank you in advance!

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

The error message is trying to tell you there are CRLF line endings, and it doesn't like the CR (`$'\r'` being a `bash` way of representing CR, carriage return).

Answer (score 1):

Using Cygwin, you need to do this before executing any bash file:

sed -i 's/\r$//' name_of_your_script.sh

Once done, you can use it normally. If you make any change in the code, use that line again.

This is because there is a problem with the CR when using bash files in Cygwin. This line eliminates those bothering CR and solves the problem.